# MapStateToProps is giving me undefined error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I'm trying to use mapStateToProps Like this :

```
const mapStateToProps = (state: { logedIn: boolean; } ) => {
return {
    logedIn: state.logedIn
}
}
```

I'm creating typescript react app.
I tried to search logedIn with ctrl search in my editor and It was found in initial state where it is supposed to be .
But when I'm doing npm start I'm getting this error :

```
  TypeError: Cannot read property 'logedIn' of undefined
Function.mapStateToProps [as mapToProps]
src/components/LogIn/Login.tsx:79
  76 | 
  77 | const mapStateToProps = (state: { logedIn: boolean; } ) => {
  78 |     return {
> 79 |         LogedIn: state.logedIn
  80 |     }
  81 | }
  82 |
```

Here is my initial state

```
interface IAppState {
    logedIn : Boolean;
}

const initialState : IAppState = {
    logedIn  : false
};

 const reducer = (state = initialState, action : any) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actionTypes.LOG_IN:
            return {
                ...state,
                logedIn: true
            }
        case actionTypes.LOG_OUT:
            return {
             ...state,
             logedIn: false
            }
    }
}
```

CreateStore :

```
export const store = createStore(reducer)
```

I'm also getting error here it is saying that no overload matches the "reducer"

Reducer :

```
   import {actionTypes} from "./actionTypes";

 export const LogedIn = () => {
    return {
        type:actionTypes.LOG_IN
    }
}

export const LogOut = () => {
    return {
        type:actionTypes.LOG_OUT
    }
}
```

Any suggestions please? I'm really stuck on these

Comment: Can you please add the code of reducer? What is the type of reducer variable, you are using in createStore.

Comment: I updated post .

Comment: Replace `const reducer` with `const reducer:Reducer<IAppState>`

Comment: And `import { Reducer } from 'redux';`

Comment: Now it is giving me this error on const reducer:Reducer<IappState>  `TS2322: Type '(state: IAppState | undefined, action: any) => { logedIn: boolean; } | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Reducer<IAppState, AnyAction>'.   Type '{ logedIn: boolean; } | undefined' is not assignable to type 'IAppState'.     Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'IAppState'.`

Comment: Sorry for disturbing you I'm just new to typescript

Comment: check my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

[`createStore`](https://redux.js.org/api/createstore#createstorereducer-preloadedstate-enhancer) accepts as second argument the initial state:

```
createStore(reducer, [preloadedState], [enhancer])
```

In your case you don't initial the store:

```
export const store = createStore(reducer, initialState)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it still does not work

Comment: What doesn't work? Can you make a reproducible example? [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vanilla-react-template-irhcq), [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I did exactly as you told me , But it is still giving me the same error for reducer

Comment: Try logging the `state` in `mapStateToProps` see what it holds.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'logedIn' of undefined`
is because the `state` passed to `mapStateToProps` is undefined. You are creating store without passing the initialState. You can resolve that error like this

> export const store = createStore(reducer)

Replace the reducer code as

```
 const reducer:Reducer<IAppState> = (state:IAppState = initialState, action : any) => {
    switch (action.type) {     
        case actionTypes.LOG_IN:
            return {
                ...state,
                logedIn: true
            }
        case actionTypes.LOG_OUT:
            return {
             ...state,
             logedIn: false
            }
    }
}
```

For an easy understanding of Redux go through [this medium article](https://medium.com/@guokai83524/building-redux-from-scratch-e12eb0e484c8)

Comment: It is still giving me error `TS2322: Type '(state: IAppState | undefined, action: any) => { logedIn: boolean; } | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Reducer<IAppState, AnyAction>'.   Type '{ logedIn: boolean; } | undefined' is not assignable to type 'IAppState'.     Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'IAppState'`

Answer (score 0):

you forget to return the state in your switch if the conditions are not met

```
    const reducer = (state = initialState, action: any) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.LOG_IN:
      return {
        ...state,
        logedIn: true
      }
    case actionTypes.LOG_OUT:
      return {
        ...state,
        logedIn: false
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```